# Слежение за запущенными приложениями C#: необходимо ли использование таймера?

Tags: c#, таймер, логирование

Здравствуйте. Мне необходимо написать приложение на С#, которое ведёт лог всех запускаемых программ и подгружаемых библиотек. Насколько я понимаю, необходимо с помощью таймера сканировать процессы, к примеру, каждые 5 секунд? Подскажите, права ли я, и есть ли другие варианты решения.

Comment: Подумайте над основным функционалом вашего приложения. Реализация таймера не так сложна, по сравнению со считыванием списка процессов, и тем более списка используемых библиотек.

Comment: Я уже нашла способ получить список процессов и подгружаемых библиотек. :) Мой вопрос только в том, необходим именно таймер, или же есть другой метод решения.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте покопать в этом направлении: `EventLog.WriteEntry` (using System.Diagnostics;)

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307024/ru